# Dependency Injection not working in PHP

Tags: php, oop, dependency-injection

I am trying to test a simple code for `dependency injection`.

**Code:**

```
class Users
{
   public function act($data){        
    echo $data;
  }    
}
class Company
{    
   public $conn;
   public function work()
   {        
    $this->conn->act('I am working');//line 60    
   }    
   public function __contruct($users)
   {
     $this->conn = $users;
   }   
}

$user = new Users();
$obj = new Company($user);
$obj->work();
```

**Problem:**

> Fatal error: Call to a member function act() on a non-object in /var/www/oop/index.php on line 60

In line 60 `$this->conn->act('I am working');`

I am using `php 5.5.9`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typo Error -: _construct not contruct

Answer (score 0):

it's because you spelled `__construct` wrong. the `s` is missing...

Mathieu